# Shift subarray to another position within the same array without temporary variable

Tags: java, arrays

Can I shift a subarray to another position within same array without using any temporary variable? For example:

```
input array = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Task = Shift {2,3} to index 4
Output array = {1,4,5,6,2,3}
```

The only way I could think of doing it was to use multiple swaps in a certain manner that could result in the required output. I am looking for a strategy that would minimize the number of swaps.

Any other suggestions on how to achieve this with or without multiple swaps is welcome.

Solution as suggested by @free6om:

```
static void shiftArray(int[] array, int i, int n, int j) {
        int count = (j - i - 1)/n;
        for (int p = 0;p < count;p++) {
            for (int q = 0;q < n;q++) {
                swap(array, i + p*n + q, i + (p+1)*n + q);
            }
            }

            for (int q = 0;q < n;q++) {
            swap(array, i + count*n + q, j + q);
            }
    }

    static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
            array[i] = array[i] + array[j];
            array[j] = array[i] - array[j];
            array[i] = array[i] - array[j];
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use *any* temporary variable (which is an arbitrary and slightly stupid restriction, since compiler is going to optimize the variable away anyway, when it's used just for swap)? Or is it just that you don't want to use a temporary array (which is sensible, since temp array size could be almost as big as original array)?

Comment: @hyde No, I don't want to use any temporary variable. I agree that the compiler will optimize the variable but I am interested in implementing it without using an explicit temporary variable by myself.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. You might want to clarify if you are interested in the array shift, or just [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). I presume the shift. Adding your current (naive?) implementation of subarray shift would also help the question.

Comment: @hyde changed the description

Comment: Also for purposes of that, the "swap without temp variable" seems irrelevant, just a small detail.

Comment: @hyde I appreciate the feedback. Changing the description once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To your update**:
The minimum swaps is `((j - i - 1)/n) * n`, where `i` is the header index of the subarray, `j` is the destination index and `n` is the length of the subarray.
One strategy to achieve this:

```
void shiftArray(int[] array, int i, int n, int j) {
    int count = (j - i - 1)/n - 1;
    for (int p = 0;p < count;p++) {
        for (int q = 0;q < n;q++) {
            swap(array, i + p*n + q, i + (p+1)*n + q);
        }
    }

    for (int q = 0;q < n;q++) {
        swap(array, i + count*n + q, j + 1 - n + q);
    }

}
```

**Original answer**:
The key point is swap without temporary variables, here is code:

```
void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    array[i] = array[i] + array[j];
    array[j] = array[i] - array[j];
    array[i] = array[i] - array[j];
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your providing the code for swap without temporary variable. Seems like my question did not clarify what I am looking for. Changing the problem description.

Comment: I am accepting your solution as it worked with a very small edit. Removed -1 from value of count, i.e. changed it to (j-i-1)/n.

Answer (score 1):

Well [free6om](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4176286/free6om) had most of it already.

I will re-use his swap method.

```
void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    array[i] = array[i] + array[j];
    array[j] = array[i] - array[j];
    array[i] = array[i] - array[j];
}
```

An alternative swap..

```
void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    if(array[i] == array[j])
        continue;
    array[i] ^= array[j];
    array[j] ^= array[i];
    array[i] ^= array[j];
}
```

Now, to your question.

```
input array = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Task = Shift {2,3} to index 4
Output array = {1,4,5,6,2,3}
```

`indx1` needs to go to `indx4` and `indx2` needs to go to `indx5`.

```
swap(array, 1, 4);
swap(array, 2, 5);
```

If you need to do more than 2 variables, use a loop or something. You would also want to check if the swap is possible (don't want an array out of bounds exception).

Comment: Question asks to shift the array to new index, not only swap the mentioned indices. Your solution would give out {1,5,6,4,2,3} as output.